# Add character between column combine in a CSV

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm looking for the correct syntax to add some (") between my variable.
I need something like that :

"firstname","lastname","email","",""

Here is the first script I have :

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\extract.csv) 
{ $firstname = $line.split(';')[0] 
$lastname = $line.split(';')[1] 
$email = $line.split(';')[2] 
$newLine = "$firstname - $lastname - $email" 
echo $newLine }
```

I'm really new in scripting and I'm a bit lost with all these (') (")

My second question is : I need to extract my data only from the second row and ignore the first one, can you help me for this too ?

Thanks !

Comment: It will be hard for others to help you without the sample input data and sample output you're looking for.

Comment: If you are splitting on semicolons `;` is the CSV a semicolon-separated instead of comma `,` separated? If so, use `Import-CSV` and specify the delimiter with `-Delimiter` parameter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try escaping your `"` and `'` ?

In powershell you can use backtick **`** (AltGr + 7) or doubling the char to do so :

Example :

```
Write-Host(" `" ")
Write-Host(" "" ")
```

Please add more code if this doesn't solve you issue !